# Factoring 4 terms without Rational Root Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lets say we have a polynomial:
$x^3 - 3x^2 - 10x + 24$

I have tried to factor the polynomial by grouping, however it doesn't work. I know the polynomial can be factored by usage of the Rational Roots Theorem, however is there another way to solve this? I feel there is a simpler way to factor this polynomial that I am missing. Thank You!

Comment: I don´t see a simpler way. In general the Rational Roots Theorem is the first method I choose if I´m facing a polynnomial with dregree 3 or more. When I´ve found one root I usually start with polynomial division.  In this case you are lucky that the Rational Roots Theorem does exist.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1):

$x^3-3x^2-10x+24=x^3-3x^2+3x-1-13x+13+12=(x-1)^3-13(x-1)+12$

By observation, $x-1=1$ gives a solution.

\begin{align*}
(x-1)^3-13(x-1)+12&=(x-1)^3-1-13(x-1)+13\\
&=[(x-1)-1][(x-1)^2+(x-1)+1-13]\\
&=(x-2)[(x-1)+4][(x-1)-3]\\
&=(x-2)(x+3)(x-4)
\end{align*}

I still prefer the Rational Roots Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

At x = 2,the polynomial is 0.
So x - 2 divides that polynomial.
Use long division dividing x - 2 into the pet polynomial to obtain a quadratic factor.
Now factor or find the roots of that quadratic.